# How clear Google Analytics ecommerce data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to clear Google Analytics ecommerce previous data?

Is there any way?

This data send to google analytics with **gtag.js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. I have struggled with this in the past and there is no good way to do this.

You can "fix" a wrong transaction sending the same ID with the same price but negative. The problem is that you must do it on the same day else your graphs ll break.